# How to change decimal number of time to date and time in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I'm a newbie in python and have a simple question in python 2.7.
I'm getting `1492500360` this number like in excel for date and time in python and want it to be converted like `2017/04/17 hh:mm:ss`.

What kind of method should I use?

I actually looked over in Google, but can't find (I might not be good at searching...)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code works:

```
lt = time.localtime(1492500360)
stime = '%4d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d' % (lt.tm_year, lt.tm_mon, lt.tm_mday, lt.tm_hour, lt.tm_min, lt.tm_sec)
```

stime is the formatted string we wanted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def TimeNow(time):
    sec = timedelta(seconds=int(time))
    dtime = datetime(1,1,1) + sec
    dnow = datetime.now()


    print("YEAR: %d \tDAY: %d \tMONTH: %d \tHOURS: %d \tMIN: %d \tSEC: %d" % (dnow.year, dtime.day, dnow.month, 
                                                                              dtime.hour, dtime.minute, dtime.second))

TimeNow(1492500360)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses datetime module. It will then grab the current time from your machine and store it in current_time. From there you can do whatever you want.

```
from datetime import datetime
current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
print current_time
```

OUTPUT: 2017/04/18 09:23:01